# How to connect to SQLite3 database in python remotely

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I use SQLite3 in python because my school computers don't allow us to install anything to python so I used the pre installed SQLite3 module.
I'm working on a program whose back end relies on an SQLite3  database, however the databases are created and stored on their computer.
Is it possible for me to "*Host*" an SQLite3 database on let's say a server and allow my script to access them remotely (my script could edit the database from my school computer)?
By the way, I'm using python 3.X

## EDIT

i made a database api that runs in python 3, its called TaliffDb
to install type `pip3 install TaliffDB` in your terminal. im working on a documentation, but please do comment if you have any questions

Comment: TaliffDB has a client and server feature(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an API on the remote server, yes. This could be hosted by a web framework of your choice.

You won't get a direct network connection to a file

Comment: define api (i iz a noobz)  and how would that help (pls upvote if u can)

Comment: You can lookup that term yourself. You're the one that said server, so how would you do that? A server doesn't just mean a website or database

Comment: I mean I know, but... do you like know any apis i could use

Comment: You write your own. That's what I said... You can use a "framework" to write an API. https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: What is it about sqlite3 that your backend relies on? If you want to host the database on a remote server, then why not just use a normal MySQL server?

Comment: If you can't install anything, though, might not be possible

Comment: @Michael That's not how upvoting works. Begging for it makes me not want to

Comment: @Marcus *school computers don't allow us to install anything*

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes but then he says that he wants to host the database on a **remote** server, and access it from his code on his school computer. So if he plans to host it on a remote server, then obviously he's not limited to his school's rules.

Comment: @Marcus I was under the impression that the project was limited to the school environment. Yes, you could use any cloud BaaS solution